# how to get the sum of selected checkboxes in android?

Tags: android, checkbox

I'am newer. I get a problem at java.

in XML, If I have 2 checkboxes,
O book
O pencil
Total is : . . .

I want to sum of selected checkboxes.
If book=10 and pencil=5.
How?

Comment: Check each one and see if they're selected.  If they are, add that amount to your total.

Comment: run counter of int type in isChecked() for O book and O pencil

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493899/android-check-box-to-total-checked. the same user

Comment: @Diah Permatasari try with your code first. Refer some tutorial for checkeboxes in android, In case of any errors or unexpected results ask here. We are not here to do your homework

Comment: what you have tried so far? Add some code related to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each of the checkboxes a unique ID in your xml (`android:id="@+id/book"`, `android:id="@+id/pencil"`) and in code check if they are checked like so:

```
int sum = 0;
if (((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.book)).isChecked()) sum += 10;
if (((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.pencil)).isChecked()) sum += 5;
```

Comment: I want to describe my xml and java. its can't. because my reputation in here just one.

Comment: If it works, accept my answer. This will also increase your reputation. But you don't need any reputation score to add your code to your question. Just paste the text and format it as code (klick the help link besides the text field to get help on how to do this).